# In SwiftUI how can I clip a part of a view with another view?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to overlap two circles in SwiftUI and have a margin between them. I am presently using this method:

```
ZStack {
    Circle()
        .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
        .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
        .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.5), radius: 4, x: 2, y: 2)
    ZStack {
        Circle()
            .frame(width: 26, height: 26)
            .foregroundColor(Color(.systemGray5))
        Circle()
            .frame(width: 22, height: 22)
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
    }
    .offset(x: 26, y: 17)
}
```

[image]

The problem is that because of the shadow on the big circle I will never be able to perfectly match the background on the smaller circle's border circle (the one that is systemGray5.  So although it looks okay, I only want the margin to appear between the circles.  Not all the way around the smaller circle.

In illustrator or other ways I would clip the big image with my 26 size circle and it would look like a bite taken out of it.  Then I can achieve this effect perfectly.

Is there anyway to clip the bottom of my large circle in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a demo of possible approach with inverted mask (it is simplified but the idea should be clear - removing hardcoding and "bite" position calculations is on you).

Tested with Xcode 13.2 / iOS 15.2

[image: demo]

```
struct DemoView: View {
    struct BiteCircle: Shape {
        func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
            let offset = rect.maxX - 26
            let crect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 26, height: 26)).offsetBy(dx: offset, dy: offset)

            var path = Rectangle().path(in: rect)
            path.addPath(Circle().path(in: crect))
            return path
        }
    }
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                .mask(BiteCircle().fill(style: .init(eoFill: true)))     // << here !!
                .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.5), radius: 4, x: 2, y: 2)

            Circle()
                .frame(width: 22, height: 22)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .offset(x: 18, y: 18)
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be helpfull

```
extension View {
@inlinable
public func reverseMask<Mask: View>(
    alignment: Alignment = .center,
    @ViewBuilder _ mask: () -> Mask
) -> some View {
    self.mask {
        Rectangle()
            .overlay(alignment: alignment) {
                mask()
                    .blendMode(.destinationOut)
            }
    }
}
```

}

You can use it so

```
ZStack {
        Circle().frame(width: 60, height: 60)
            .reverseMask { 
                Circle().frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                    .offset(x: 20, y: 20)
            }
        Circle().frame(width: 20, height: 20)
            .offset(x: 20, y: 20)
    }
    .foregroundColor(.blue)
    .shadow(color: .black, radius: 4)
```