# SwiftUI: drawing a shape with curves in the middle and edges

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm struggling in drawing the following shape in SwiftUI:

[image]

I could draw half a circle like this:

```
 Circle()
                .trim(from: 0.05, to: 0.45)
                .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
```

but I still can't figure out how to glue this circle with rounded edges to create the final shape.
I need to use an `HStack` that has this shape.

Comment: I'd say you need to create custom Shape of composed path, or, as alternate, try some standard using inverted masks, like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/71021134/12299030. Custom shape seems simpler as for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom shape seems to fit best here. With it you can use the `.clipShape` modifier to achieve what you want:

```
struct MyShape: Shape{
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let width = rect.size.width
        let height = rect.size.height
        let circleWidth = width * 0.2
        
        let point1 = CGPoint(x: 0, y: height)
        let point2 = CGPoint(x: 0, y: height * 0.2)
        let point3 = CGPoint(x: width * 0.4, y: 0)
        let point4 = CGPoint(x: width * 0.8, y: 0)
        let point5 = CGPoint(x: width, y: height)
        
        return Path{ path in
            path.move(to: point1)
            path.addLine(to: point2)
            path.addArc(center: .init(x: width * 0.1, y: width * 0.1), radius: width * 0.1, startAngle: .init(degrees: 180), endAngle: .init(degrees: 270), clockwise: false)
            path.addLine(to: point3)
            path.addArc(center: .init(x: width / 2, y: 0), radius: circleWidth / 2, startAngle: .init(degrees: 180), endAngle: .init(degrees: 0), clockwise: true)
            path.addLine(to: point4)
            path.addArc(center: .init(x: width * 0.9, y: width * 0.1), radius: width * 0.1, startAngle: .init(degrees: 270), endAngle: .init(degrees: 0), clockwise: false)
            path.addLine(to: point5)
            path.closeSubpath()
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
HStack{
        Rectangle()
    }
    .clipShape(MyShape())
```

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: excellent and clean solution, thank you, this did the job.

Comment: if i want to show only 1/3 of the middle circle, like the circle in the question's  screenshot, what should i do to achieve this ?

Comment: You would need to move the center point in the 2nd `addArc` call up with an -y value and change the start and end angle. Some simple circle geometry should tell you the exact values. `segment of a circle` should be the keyword here. Perhaps I will try something tomorrow.

Comment: I guess i figured it out, the second arc would be: `path.addArc(center: .init(x: width / 2, y: -20), radius: circleWidth / 2, startAngle: .init(degrees: 150), endAngle: .init(degrees: 30), clockwise: true)` and I need to fix some other values to let the shape be perfect

Answer (score 1):

i was change and add some modification to my shape here is code

```
 struct MyShape: Shape {
let circlePosition: CGPoint
func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
    let width = rect.size.width
    let height = rect.size.height
    var circleWidth = width * 0.16// Initial circle width
    
    // Increase the circle width (radius) by a factor
    let scaleFactor: CGFloat = 1.5
    circleWidth *= scaleFactor
    
    let topRadius: CGFloat = 50
    
    let point1 = CGPoint(x: 0, y: height)
    let point2 = CGPoint(x: 0, y: height * 0.2)
    let point3 = CGPoint(x: width * 0.4, y: 0)
    let point4 = CGPoint(x: width * 0.8, y: 0)
    let point5 = CGPoint(x: width, y: height)
    
    return Path { path in
        path.move(to: point1)
        path.addLine(to: point2)
        
        path.addArc(center: .init(x: width * 0.1, y: width * 0.1), radius: topRadius, startAngle: .init(degrees: 180), endAngle: .init(degrees: 270), clockwise: false)
        
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: circlePosition.x - circleWidth / 2, y: 0))
        path.addArc(center: circlePosition, radius: circleWidth / 2, startAngle: .init(degrees: 180), endAngle: .init(degrees: 0), clockwise: true)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: circlePosition.x + circleWidth / 2, y: 0))
        
        path.addLine(to: point4)
        path.addArc(center: .init(x: width * 0.9, y: width * 0.1), radius: topRadius, startAngle: .init(degrees: 270), endAngle: .init(degrees: 0), clockwise: false)
        path.addLine(to: point5)
        path.closeSubpath()
    }
} }
```